# How to show last line of one TextFormField with fixed number of lines in Flutter

Tags: flutter, line, textfield

I have a TextFormField with a fixed number of lines and when a screen load, this TextFormField already have more lines then a fixed number of lines that i defined,

and if i want to see the last line,

I need manually scroll it to the last line.

Is there a way to show automatically the last line of this TextFormField?

```
    Container(
                  child:  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: TextField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      maxLines: 9,
                      controller: chatController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Chat...",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: https://github.com/gregoriLima

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a missing feature in the Flutter Framework, Someone has filed a bug to get it resolved: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9365

However site includes a work around. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

1. make this public variable:

   ```
   ScrollController scrollController = new ScrollController();
   ```
2. attach it to the TextField

   ```
   TextField(
     //...
     scrollController: scrollController,
     //...
   ),
   ```
3. put this into your initState function:

   ```
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
          scrollController.jumpTo(double.parse((9 * 17 * 1.9 /*number of lines * fontSize * 1.9 (you can of course experiment with this values)*/).toStringAsFixed(1)));
   });
   ```

i hope it helped